# ANTLR, optional ';' in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, antlr3

I'm just playing with ANTLR and decided to try parsing JavaScript with it. But I hit the wall in dealing with optional ';' in it, where statement end is marked by newline instead. Can it be done in some straightforward way?

Just a simple grammar example that doesn't work

```
grammar optional_newline;
def         : statements ;
statements  : statement (statement)* ;
statement   : expression (';' | '\n') ;
expression  : ID | INT | 'var' ID '=' INT ;
ID          : ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|'_') ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|'0'..'9'|'_')* ;
INT         : '0'..'9'+ ;
WS          : ( ' ' | '\t' | '\r' | '\n') {$channel=HIDDEN;} ;
```

and I want to be able to parse this (which can be parsed by JavaScript parsers)

```
var i = 
10
10;
```

PS: I don't want to put `WS` in parser rules, I would be much happier if lexer just get rid of those.

Comment: I presume you've looked into the ECMA-script grammars posted on the ANLR-wiki: http://www.antlr.org/grammar/list ?

Comment: @Bart, yes I did, but there they specifically allow whitespaces in every rule. I don't like it that way, although I suspect it is the only way possible. But I hope I'm wrong and someone knows how to do solve this problem without making a mess out of grammar.

Comment: I thought you had, but wanted to make sure. I'll think about it too, although I suspect there's no way around it...

Answer (score 0):

i'm not sure if this will work in all cases possible in javascript, but it correctly parses your example:

```
grammar js;

def         : statements ;
statements  : statement (statement)* ;
statement   : expression ';'? ;
expression  : ID | INT | 'var' ID '=' INT ;
ID          : ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|'_') ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|'0'..'9'|'_')* ;
INT         : '0'..'9'+ ;
WS          : ( ' ' | '\t' | '\r' | '\n') {$channel=HIDDEN;} ;
```

[alt text http://img249.imageshack.us/img249/7131/parsetree.jpg](http://img249.imageshack.us/img249/7131/parsetree.jpg)

Comment: But it will also parse `10 10`, which is not allowed :)

Comment: could you explain where a semicolon should be required and where it should be optional? i'd have to take a look at the javascript syntax for details, might take a while..

Comment: It's more or less easy, every ';' meaning the end of sentence can be replaced by newline. But in all other cases newlines just ignored.